# SQL Server 2012 - How to Remove Partition on Publisher but not Subscriber?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

Is it possible to setup partitioning on a SQL Server 2012 publisher table, so that older data can be removed without affecting the same table on a subscriber table?

Table exists on `Database A (SQL Server 2012 - app DB)` to store a `varchar(max)` field that is populated by a web app, and never referenced again. Table is replicated to `Database B (SQL Server 2012 - data mining DB)` where it will be used for `reporting/data mining`.

Would like to partition table on both DBs by quarter and only have data from current quarter on Database A (Database B will have historical quarters).

Comment: Transactional Replication

Answer (score 1):

You can override the way DELETE commands are replicated to the subscriber by using the @del_cmd parameter for [sp_addarticle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms173857.aspx). You can specify a custom stored procedure that takes care of the archive logic or ignore DELETE commands altogether by setting it to NONE.

However, the rows kept at the subscriber **won't be replicated any more if for some reason you re-initialize the subscription**, which I suppose is not exactly desirable.

I don't think that replication is the right way to skin this cat. Probably a custom SSIS package would do the trick more cleanly.

Comment: Thanks. I had wondered about the SSIS approach as well. Was thinking a nightly job that merges the Database A table partition into a staging table, where Database B picks up the data and truncates the staging table. Then, Database A merges partition with new date for next day's data.